# Cocos2d: Preloading animation causes a crash

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to preload an animation in the init method of my layer. I then call the animation if the screen is touched. The app crashes with no error message as soon as I touch the screen and seems it is to do with calling the preloaded animation. I would like to do it this way as it seems expensive to create the animation every time the screen is touched - which does seems to work though. Any tips greatly appreciated.

Sample Code:

In my header:

```
@interface Test : CCLayer {
   NSMutableArray *wake;
   CCSprite* ani;
   CCAnimate *animate;
}
@end
```

In my implementation:

```
    -(id) init {
        if( (self=[super init])) {      
    // enable touches
    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"ani.plist" texture:[[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ani.png"]]];
            ani = [CCSprite  spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"ani1.png"]; //comes from .plist file
            ani.anchorPoint=ccp(0,0);
            ani.position = ccp(700,65); 
            [self addChild:ani z:30];

    wake = [NSMutableArray array];
            for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
                [wake addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ani%d.png",i]]];
            }
            animate = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:[CCAnimation animationWithFrames:wake delay:1.0f] restoreOriginalFrame:FALSE];

        }
        return self;                                                   
    }
```

Handling the touch:

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
// run the animation
   [ani runAction:animate];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by creating properties for the array and animation on the class using nonatomic,retain.

Answer (score 0):

Animations in Cocos2d are not designed to be reused. You need to create a new one every time.

Comment: So do you need to load the array everytime? surely this must be a performance hit?

Comment: You can cache the wake array but you need to call animate = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:[CCAnimation animationWithFrames:wake delay:1.0f] restoreOriginalFrame:FALSE]; every time.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to retain the animation but the array can be local.

```
self.myAnimation = [[CCAnimation animationWithFrames:myAniFramesArray delay:0.1f] retain];
```

Remember to make the property nonatomic, retain as stated by Chev and to release any objects you retain in the appropriate dealloc method.